# Adding rows onto 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays

The method assigned in the assignment says:

boolean addLineSegment(int [] segment) - add a line segment to the database if its coordinates represent a valid line segment. This should increase the size of the lineSegment array by one and add the given line segment to the end. The method returns true if a line segment was added and false otherwise. The input should be an array of size 4.

I'm kind of stuck because I want to add a row into my array lineSegments[][] without having to reallocate it and erasing the previous contents of the array. How do I keep the contents of the array and add a new row to it so I can add the contents of segment[] to lineSegments[][]?

```
public boolean addLineSegment(int[] segment) {

    if(segment.length==4 && isValid(segment[0], segment[1], segment[2], segment[4])){
        //does something that copies segment into a new row of lineSegments...
        returns true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: If allowed, use `ArrayList`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I think... that will most probably defeat the purpose of this assignment. I feel the purpose of this assignment is to develop an understanding of programming... So I think the learning and experience gained by effort in solving is targeted instead of actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Java if you want to expand a primitive array you need to allocate new space and copy the entire array. There is no mechanism to expand in place (because the space after the array in memory is not part of the array).

Fortunately it's a pretty trivial thing to do in Java as `Arrays.copyOf` does exactly what you want it to do. You can expand the size by 1 and enter the new data.

A slightly more sophisticated way to do it is to allocate more space than initially required and keep a separate `lineCount` variable. Then you can expand in blocks (when `lineCount == array.length`) rather than each time a new line is added.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this through array unless you copy your array to a  new big array.

I would suggest you use java collection instead.List>.